# dojo.date.locale.parse returns null

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

I've setup a example on fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/ANY6K/

```
require([
    "dojo/date/locale"
], function( locale ) {    
    var dateString = "Jan 20, 2014 12:30:00 AM"
    var date = dojo.date.locale.parse(dateString, {datePattern: "MMM dd, yyyy", timePattern: "HH:mm:ss a"})
    console.log(date);

});
```

In my case, the example fails on my Windows 7 (64 bit) machine using Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m.
It works with dojo 1.8 or below but anything higher than 1.8, it returns null.  Why?

Also, it works on my ubuntu 13.10 with chromium 34.0.1847.xxx (even with dojo 1.9.3)

Comment: Not a fix, but you can change `dojo.date.locale.parse(...)` to `locale.parse(...)`. You're using the VERY old way of invoking dojo functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should test the output with given format parameters, it should give you the idea, what is expected when parsing:

```
require([
    "dojo/date/locale"
], function( locale ) {    
    var dateString = locale.format(new Date(), {datePattern: "MMM dd, yyyy", 
        timePattern: "HH:mm:ss a"})
    console.log(dateString)
});
```

> > Jun 02, 2014, 09:16:16 AM

I couldn't run your example on my Windows machine (IE and FF, so not only a Chrome issue), but well, judging from the output format, it seems that comma is required. After adding the missing comma, it worked on both browsers:

```
var dateString = "Jan 20, 2014, 12:30:00 AM"
```

Second, if you operate on the month names, you need to specify locale as well:

```
var date = locale.parse(dateString, {datePattern: "MMM dd, yyyy", 
        timePattern: "HH:mm:ss a", locale: "en-US"})
```

because otherwise, the given example won't function, if the locale in the browser is other as the "EN".

I've tested on **Dojo 1.9**, Windows 7, IE and FF.

I can't test that on Linux machine, but if the same code would be OS-dependent, it would be quite a nasty bug in Dojo.